# Saving data to ElasticSearch in Spark task

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming, elasticsearch-java-api, spark-avro

While processing a stream of Avro messages through Kafka and Spark, I am saving the processed data as documents in a ElasticSearch index. 
Here's the code (simplified):

```
    directKafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd ->{

        rdd.foreach(avroRecord -> {
            byte[] encodedAvroData = avroRecord._2;
            MyType t = deserialize(encodedAvroData);

    // Creating the ElasticSearch Transport client
    Settings settings = Settings.builder()
            .put("client.transport.ping_timeout", 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
    TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
            .addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));

    IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest("index", "item", id)
            .source(jsonBuilder()
                    .startObject()
                    .field("name", name)
                    .field("timestamp", new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                    .endObject());

    UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest("index", "item", id)
            .doc(jsonBuilder()
                    .startObject()
                    .field("name", name)
                    .field("timestamp", new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                    .endObject())
            .upsert(indexRequest);

    client.update(updateRequest).get();

    client.close();
```

Everything works as expected; the only problem is performance: saving to ES requires some time, and I suppose that this is due to the fact that I open/close an ES Transport client for each RDD. Spark [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#design-patterns-for-using-foreachrdd) suggests that this approach is quite correct: as soon as I understand, the only possible optimisation is using rdd.foreachPartition, but I only have one partition, so I am not sure that this would be beneficial. 
Any other solution to achieve better performance?

Comment: just out of curiosity - why you don't use elasticsearch-hadoop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you create new connect whenever process a record of RDD.
So, I think use `foreachPartition` will make better performance regardless of only one partition, because it help you bring your ES connection instance outside, reuse it in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would stream the processed messages back onto a separate Kafka topic, and then use Kafka Connect to land them to [Elasticsearch](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-elasticsearch/docs/elasticsearch_connector.html). This decouples your Spark-specific processing from getting the data into Elasticsearch.

Example of it in action: https://www.confluent.io/blog/blogthe-simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-in-the-world-or-thereabouts-part-2/